# how to remove special characters from string in Java

Tags: java, special-characters

```
<%@page import="java.net.URLDecoder"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@page import="java.net.URLDecoder"%>
  <%@page import="java.net.URLEncoder"%>
<html>
<form action="index.jsp">
    <body>
        First INPUT:
        <input name="firstinput" type="text" name="fname">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        <%
            String first = request.getParameter("firstinput");
              String Searchtext=URLDecoder.decode(first,"UTF-8");
            out.println(Searchtext);

            out.println(URLEncoder.encode(Searchtext,"UTF-8"));
        %>

 </body>
 </form>
</html>
```

This is My code I want to Encode and Decode text in Jsp Actully I want that when Input Text " ",' ',/ /...any special charter it should print same as it is text like if Input "hello" or hello then it should Print hello or if input 'hello' then also it should Print hello... special charter should Not display please help me i am Unable to do this ...

Comment: believe me... you are able to do this :)

Comment: Am not able to do this please help ...

Comment: So, you just want to remove the chars `",'/`?

Comment: yes i want if we Enter Input text : "Hello" or 'hello' or...\hello\ Then it should Print Only text Special charter should not print

Comment: I fixed a severe terminology mistake in title. Removal of characters has got completely nothing to do with encoding/decoding. Removal is irreversible. Encoding/decoding is changing "incompatible" characters by "compatible" characters in a reversible way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
String lWithoutSpecials = first.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha}]+","");
```

For me it works great:

```
String s = "\\Hello\\ \"Hello\" 'Hello'";
String lWithoutSpecials = s.replaceAll("[^\\p{Alpha}]+", "");
System.out.println(lWithoutSpecials);
```

Output:

> HelloHelloHello

Comment: I want if Input start with Special charter +text+ End with Special charter then it should print only Text it should not Print special charter

Comment: But i am taking Input from Input box In Jsp ...please take Input from JSp

Comment: then replace Searchtext with first.

Comment: Please check it in Dynamic web PRoject it will Not work .. In jsp

Comment: if i want that Space should be there in Text if Enter "hello World" Then it should Print hello world then how i will apply

Answer (score 0):

You are not using full Unicode but Latin-1, ISO-8859-1. This Latin-1 will browsers
interprete as MS Windows Latin-1, or "Cp-1252"/"Windows-1252". This charset has some special characters like comma like quotes, € (euro), etcetera.

URL encoding/decoding is done automatically. The data entry of the input may
cause numeric HTML entities to arrive at the server, like `&#1234;` when having a restricted charset like Latin-1. With UTF-8 for the entire Unicode characters you need to add to the `<form accept-charset="UTF8">` to prevent substitution by numeric entities.

A HTML 5 form:

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=Windows-1252"
     pageEncoding="Windows-1252"
     import="java.net.URLDecoder"
     import="java.net.URLEncoder"
%><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>First Input</title>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="index.jsp">
        First INPUT:
        <input name="firstinput" type="text"
               value="${param.firstinput}">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        <%
            String first = request.getParameter("firstinput");
            String searchtext = first;
            out.println(searchtext);
        %>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

It lies saying its charset is the limited ISO-8859-1, but java delivers the larger charset Windows-1252.

The tag `<form>` must be inside the `<body>`. If you did that for form margins and such, use CSS styles.